# SQL XML Insert attribute to node

Tags: sql, xml

I need to add an attribute tag='plan' to the column tisa_LayoutURL with the node Image. See my query below

```
select @xml = 
    (
            SELECT art.tisa_Code AS [@internal-id],
                cla.tisa_image1 AS [image], '',
                cla.tisa_image2 AS [image], '',
                cla.tisa_image3 AS [image], '',
                cla.tisa_image4 AS [image], '',
                art.tisa_LayoutUrl AS [image],
                addr.tisa_Description AS [description]
    FROM tisa_article art JOIN 
         tisa_Address addr ON addr.tisa_AddressId = art.tisa_AddressId JOIN
         tisa_Classifier cla ON cla.tisa_classifierid = addr.tisa_classifierid 
    JOIN
         Account Acc ON Acc.AccountId=cla.tisa_vendorid
    FOR XML PATH('offer'), root('realty-feed'))
```

I need to obtain the following:

```
<image>xxxxx.jpg</image>
<image>xxxx1.jpg</image>
<image>xxxx2.jpg</image>
<image>xxxx3.jpg</image>
<image tag="plan">xxxx4.jpg</image>
```

how can i modify my query to achieve that?

Comment: I'm assuming you are working in a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
art.tisa_LayoutUrl AS [image],
```

with:

```
'plan' AS "image/@tag",
art.tisa_LayoutUrl AS [image],
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!